# clear all bits from MSB through i (inclusive)

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

Below is the code about clearing all the MSB’s (Most Significant Bits) through i (inclusive)

```
public int clearBitsMSBThrough(int num, int i) {
    int mask = ( 1 << (i + 1) ) - 1;
    return num & mask;
}
```

I am confused about "inclusive". 
For example, if the number is 0011 1010 and i = 3.
mask will be 0000 1111, and result is 0000 1010,but the bit in position 3 is not cleared as zero.

Am I misunderstanding the question?
And I think it should be:

```
int mask = (1 << i) - 1;
```

Comment: `Am I misunderstanding the question?` what's the question?

Comment: The question is write a method to clear all bits from MSB to i (inclusive) . Thanks!

Comment: Then, it looks like you already know what the problem and the solution are, since you said "`I think it should be: int mask = (1 << i) - 1;`"

Answer (score 3):

```
public int clearBitsMSBThrough(int num, int i) {    
   int mask = (1 << i) - 1;
   return num & mask;
}
```

Skimming through the [binary subtraction](http://www.helpwithpcs.com/courses/binary-numbers.htm) might help in this regard.